# javascript inheritance - '...is not defined'. Namespace issue?

Tags: javascript

I have a 'class' called `ModuleSelector` that grabs a list of modules from a server and displays them as clickable toggle buttons. I'm trying to create a class called `Module` that extends the `ToggleButton` class and is only visible to the `ModuleSelector`.

The problem I'm having is that the line:

`Module.prototype = new ToggleButton();` is giving an error: `ToggleButton is not defined`.

I don't understand why it cannot be found, because I can create new instances of ToggleButton inside the `Module` function, for example.

**ModuleSelector.js**

```
(function() {

    function Module(id,name){
        this.moduleID = id;
        this.moduleName = name;
        this.topics = [];

        this.addTopic = function(topic){
            this.topics.push(topic);
        }
    }

    Module.prototype = new ToggleButton();
    Module.prototype.constructor = Module;

    var ModuleSelector = function (id) {
        this.initialize(id);
    };

    var p = ModuleSelector.prototype = new createjs.Container();
    p.Container_initialize = p.initialize;
    p.initialize = function (id) {
        this.Container_initialize();
        //.....
    };

    window.ModuleSelector = ModuleSelector;
}());
```

**ToggleButton.js**

```
(function() {
    var ToggleButton = function(text) {
        this.initialize(text);
        //....code
    };

    var p = ToggleButton.prototype = new createjs.Container();
    p.Container_initialize = p.initialize;
    p.initialize = function(text) {
        this.Container_initialize();
    };

    window.ToggleButton = ToggleButton;
}());
```

Comment: Yeah, you have it wrapped in a `(function () {}());` which basically puts it in a different namespace. Just wrap them both in one `(function ...)` or simply remove that wrapper all together. That would be my solution.

Comment: Are you sure ToggleButton.js is loaded before ModuleSelector.js? I'd check that.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, that was the problem! Silly me

Comment: Oh, I see. I missed the `window.` assignments at the bottom.

Comment: Notice that [`.prototpye = new ParentConstructor` is wrong anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592913/what-is-the-reason-to-use-the-new-keyword-here) (and afair it actually matters for createjs).